# Rails 3.1 Advanced Has_many and belongs_to model joins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two tables. Items, and Vendors. Items are sold by Vendors. So Item belongs_to :vendor and Vendor has_many :items. That works fine.

However, Items are not always manufactured by the Vendors that sell them, but sometimes they are. So I have a new column in my Item table called "manufacturer_id". Rather than generate a new model called Manufacturer that duplicates Vendor identically, I tried to do a complex has_many and belongs_to to define manufacturer.

See here:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :vendor
  belongs_to :manufacturer, :class_name => "Vendor", :foreign_key => "manufacturer_id"
end

class Vendor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items
  has_many :manufactured_items, :class_name => "Item", :foreign_key => "manufacturer_id"
end
```

Populating manufacturer_id in the items table works as expected on Create commands:

```
Item.create(:manufacturer => Vendor.find_by_abbrev("INV"))
```

And I can even get the manufacturer as the operation

```
item.manufacturer
```

which returns:

```
<Vendor:0x007ff06684e398>
```

HOWEVER:

```
item.manufacturer.name
```

fails completely with a hard exeption and I get the error:

```
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

running

```
debug item.manufacturer
```

gives

```
--- !ruby/object:Vendor
attributes:
  id: 181
  name: Invitrogen
  website: http://www.invitrogen.com/
  created_at: 2012-01-08 01:39:07.486375000Z
  updated_at: 2012-01-08 01:39:07.486375000Z
  abbrev: INV
```

so item.manufacturer.name should return the name for that vendor object above, Vendor: 0x007ff06684e398.

What am I doing wrong here?

Also, once I get this working I'd like to be able to similarly call:

```
vendor.manufactured_items
```

to get all the items that have the manufacturer_id of that vendor. is there a straightforward way to do that too?

My last ditch effort may involve having to do:

manufacturer = Vendor.new(item.manufacturer)

But that seems totally wrong, and goes against the rails documentation here:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins

please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I've actually built a demo Rails 3.1 project for you and [posted it on GitHub](https://github.com/normalocity/vendors-demo). I've included the console output in the `README` file to prove that calls like `item.seller.name` and `item.manufacturer.name` work, as well as round-trip calls like `vendor.sold_items.first.manufacturer.name`, which allow you to get the name of the manufacturer of the first sold item for a particular vendor, for example.

I think the root of the thing, as you noted, is that a `vendor` and a `manufacturer`, for all intents and purposes, are identical. For that reason I combined them simply into the `Vendor` class, and setup the foreign key relationships in such a way that it should work the way I think you want it to.

In particular, you should pay attention to the [**README**](https://github.com/normalocity/vendors-demo/blob/master/README) file, which has the console session output that I ran to show it working. You'll also want to take a look at the two model classes and how their associations are defined, as well as the `spec/factories.rb` file for how it sets up the fake database data (I've included those below).

In re-reading your question this morning, I'm not sure what you were doing wrong, but you can probably chalk it up to a subtle error in your associations somewhere. It's probably a case of you being *really* close, but not quite there. :D

Here's some snipets from the code:

**app/models/item.rb**

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :seller, :class_name => "Vendor"
  belongs_to :manufacturer, :class_name => "Vendor"
end
```

**app/models/vendor.rb**

```
class Vendor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sold_items, :class_name => "Item", :foreign_key => :seller_id
  has_many :manufactured_items, :class_name => "Item", :foreign_key => :manufacturer_id
end
```

**spec/factories.rb**

```
require 'populator'
require 'faker'

FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :vendor do |v|
    v.name            {Populator.words(1..3)}
    v.website         {Faker::Internet.domain_name}
    v.abbr            {(["ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "JKL", "MNO", "PQR", "STU", "VWX", "YZ1"])[rand(9)]}
  end

  factory :item do |i|
    i.association :seller, :factory => :vendor
    i.association :manufacturer, :factory => :vendor
    i.name  {Populator.words(3..5)}
  end

end
```

**lib/tasks/populator.rake**

```
namespace :db do  
  desc "Erase database"
  task :erase => :environment do
    puts "Erasing..."

    [Vendor, Item].each(&:delete_all)
  end

  desc "Erase and fill database"
  task :populate => [:environment, :erase] do
    require 'populator'
    require 'faker'

    puts "Populating: enjoy this random pattern generator while you wait..."

    50.times{Factory.create(:vendor)}
    Vendor.all.each do |v|
      # This line actually has a bug in it that makes all `seller_id` and `manufacturer_id`
      # columns always contain a value in the range 0..50. That means
      # `rake db:populate` will only actually work the first time, but
      # I think you get the idea of how this should work.
      10.times{Factory.create(:item, :seller_id => (rand(50) + 1), :manufacturer_id => (rand(50) + 1))}
      print (['\\', '/', '_', '|'])[rand(4)]
    end

    puts ""
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks for your input but unfortunately that did not solve my problem. telling me to google for answers is also not helping. did you see my details described above? item.manufacturer returns a vendor object, but it cannot respond to vendor methods like name.

Comment: I'm just on my phone answering this, hoping to point you in the right direction. I'll take a closer look at this tomorrow and refine my answer. Don't worry - I'm not done yet.

Comment: Hm, I'm working through a bug where I can't do calls like `vendor.sold_items` - I'll update the code shortly.

Comment: Fixed the bug, updated the README file with the latest console tests, and confirmed that associations are working in both directions. Changes pushed to the GitHub repo I referenced in the answer.

Comment: FANTASTIC THANKS!!!!! This is extremely helpful and detailed and the code is great. I can confirm it WORKED for me. You are awesome, thanks!!!